# Reset variable after for error message

Tags: javascript, php

I am attempting to create a PHP method/function/property that I can call with JS to display a message to the user such as "Invalid user login" which will then reset after it has displayed.

So far I have below - problem is when the user goes to the next page, or reloads they are given the message again, so I am wanting away of setting it back to null;

```
<script>

window.setTimeout(displayErrorMessage(), 2000);

function displayErrorMessage(){

if(!displayErrorMessage.called)
{
var errorMessage = ("<?php echo "ERROR: ".$_SESSION['error'] ?>");
document.getElementById('errormessage').innerHTML = errorMessage;
resetErrorMessage();
}

displayErrorMessage.called = true;
}

function resetErrorMessage()
  { 
    var errorMessage = null;

   setTimeout(function()
    {
    document.getElementById('errormessage').innerHTML = "";

    }, 5000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: check for the value or existence of `$_SESSION['error']` before outputting the script

Comment: Problem is, once it has been set by an error handler that variable is always set. I am looking for away of clearing it once I have displayed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the session variable after display.

```
<script>
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) { ?>
    window.setTimeout(displayErrorMessage(), 2000);

    function displayErrorMessage(){
            if(!displayErrorMessage.called) {
                    var errorMessage = ('<?php echo "ERROR: ".$_SESSION['error']; ?>');
                    // Here is where you remove the error so it won't persist to the
                    // next pages when user continues to navigate through
                    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) unset($_SESSION['error']); ?>
                    document.getElementById('errormessage').innerHTML = errorMessage;
                    resetErrorMessage();
                }

            displayErrorMessage.called = true;
        }
    <?php } ?>

    function resetErrorMessage() { 
            var errorMessage = null;
            setTimeout(function(){
                    document.getElementById('errormessage').innerHTML = "";
                }, 5000);
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php if( isset($_SESSION['error']) ) : ?>
<script>
window.setTimeout(displayErrorMessage(), 2000);

function displayErrorMessage()
{
    if(!displayErrorMessage.called)
    {
        var errorMessage = ("<?php echo "ERROR: ".$_SESSION['error'] ?>");
        document.getElementById('errormessage').innerHTML = errorMessage;
        resetErrorMessage();
    }

    displayErrorMessage.called = true;
}

function resetErrorMessage()
{ 
    var errorMessage = null;

    setTimeout(function() {
                   document.getElementById('errormessage').innerHTML = "";
               }, 5000);
}
</script>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
unset($_SESSION['error']);
?>
```